# Error in Insert query using Python 3

Tags: python, sql

I have a Players table with 3 columns id, name, wins
I want to insert a row into this table. Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("tournament.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
name_insert = 'David'
wins = 10
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Players(name,wins) VALUES (%s,%s)",(name_insert,wins))
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

I got this error "sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error".
Could you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLite Python module uses `?` as the placeholder for parameters, not `%s`.

Check https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle

Therefore, your code should work just changing the `.execute` call to:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Players(name,wins) VALUES (?, ?)",(name_insert,wins))
```